# Displaying cURL JSON response with Dingo API (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm sending a requests via `cURL` to an external webservice and I'm receiving a response in JSON format. Something like this:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $loggedInUser = app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->user();
    if (!$loggedInUser instanceof User) {
        $this->response->errorUnauthorized();
    }

    $data = $request->all();

    $url = env('WEBSERVICE_URL');
    $payload = json_encode(['n' => $data['n']]);

    $auth = 'Authorization: ' . env('API_KEY');

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        $auth
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

The problem is that the response of function is like this

```js
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "success",
    "data": "{\"message\":\"n saved successfully!\"}"
}
```

And not like this (the json I received from the webservice)

```js
{"message": "n saved successfully!"}
```

I'm not really an expert with Dingo API but I can imagine that this probably has to do with some kind of default response format Dingo applies to the returned values in the functions.

Anyways, in this case I would like it to return the second response above mentioned. Is there any way to disable the default response format Dingo applies in particular cases? Or do you think this is caused by something else?

Comment: Could you please show the python code?

Comment: It's PHP. And what python code do you mean?

Comment: I think about django, sorry. Show me please Dingo API code?